# How to apply this interesting animation on navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web-frontend

I am trying to create the navigation bar with this effect:

The navigation bar is transparent, when scrolled down, it disappears with subtle animation, when scrolled up (regardless of where we are on the page - middle or end), it appears with white background and if we keep scrolling up it becomes sticky until we reach the top, and as we reach the top its white background turns transparent again. [See here.](https://pagebolt.uicore.co)

I looked into [this script](https://pagebolt.uicore.co/business/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/uicore-global.js?ver=1971), but since I know nothing of jQuery, I was unable to figure it out, I did find the relevant [snippet](https://ctxt.io/2/AADQm9_cEw), but don't know how does all this work.

In order to solve this problem, I applied the following JS, but did not achieve the desired result

```
const header = document.querySelector('.header');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
if (window.scrollY > 10) {
header.classList.add('active');
} 
else {
header.classList.remove('active');
}
});
```

I am looking for guidance to achieve the same effect on my navigation bar.

Many thanks!

Comment: JavaScript is not the only thing needed here. Do you have a `.active` selector in your CSS? Put the first line inside the scroll handler, the `.header` element might not exist yet when `addEventListender` is called. This is not jQuery, only add relevant tags to the question.

Answer (score -1):

are u sure that u have an element with class "**header**" or u are using the header tag  () ? and also ur CSS will be required to provide more accurate assistance.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).